# kendo date picker template set name with b'date

Tags: datepicker, kendo-ui

i am try kendo date picker customize template.
i want to set name with date here is demo of kendo template.
http://demos.kendoui.com/web/datepicker/template.html

and here is birth-date

```
 birthdays = [
                           new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 11),
                           new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 6),
                           new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 27),
                           new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() - 1, 3),
                           new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() - 2, 22),
                           new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 23)
                        ];
```

here i want to set name with b'date like 11-Aug set Name Chian. 
and on mouse over show this name.
any idea how can i do this.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you can do that, too. You have to prepare JSON for that. You would like to do it in this manner.

```
birthdays = [
    new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 11, 'Frnd1'),
    new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 6, 'Frnd2'),
    new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 27, 'Frnd3'),
    new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() - 1, 3, 'Frnd4'),
    new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() - 2, 22, 'Frnd5'),
    new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 23, 'Frnd6')
];
```

Actually, the text you are seeing is due to `title` attribute of its parent `<a>` tag.

You can include name of the birthday guy in the JSON object, and then you may like to change its parent `<a>`'s title by below code.

```
$('.birthday').find(function(){
   $(this).parent().attr('title', #=data.name #');
});
```